# NextJS - After moving pages to app directory none of my images are working

Tags: next.js, plesk, nextjs-image

I'm running a Next JS application on Plesk and I recently moved all of my pages to the app directory, as this is the new standard. However, I'm unable to get **any** of my images to work, apart from the ones that are hosted externally. It seems to be a problem with resolving the hostname, as the error I'm getting is an econnrefused error. Does anyone know what could be causing this? The website is located at kwekerijvantuyl.nl.

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

Comment: No, it is exactly the other way around. The ones that are hosted externally, so not on my own domain do actually work. The ones that I have stored locally do not work

Comment: The error which Next JS gives is "url" parameter is valid but upstream response is invalid, if you edit the node_modules and change this to throw the actual error instead, it throws an ECONNREFUSED

Comment: your images are getting 500 as a response. there is an issue created, https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53715

Comment: This issue has been closed and is supposed to be fixed already. Also, the images are working perfectly fine locally, so it might be a server issue